# The relationship between the symmetric tensor product and sum of squares

Tags: polynomials, sums-of-squares

I would like to understand deeply the relationship between the symmetric tensor product of order 2 and the sum of squares.

For me, it is clear that the symmetric tensor product or order $d$ is isomorphic to the set of the homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$. I want to know precisely if it is true the following statement:

If $V$ is a vector space of monomials, then $Sym^2(V)$ is the space of the polynomials that can be written as a sum of squares?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true.
First of all, if $V$ is a vector space *spanned by* monomials of some degree $d$,
then $V$ is a vector space *of* (homogeneous) polynomials (of degree $d$).
Then $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ is *not* identified
with the polynomials of $2d$,
for example $(x^2)(yz)$ and $(xy)(xz)$ are different elements of
$\operatorname{Sym}^2(\operatorname{span}\{x^2,xy,\dotsc,z^2\})$,
although of course they map to the same polynomials.
(In general if $V = \operatorname{Sym}^d(W)$,
then
$\operatorname{Sym}^e(V) = \operatorname{Sym}^e(\operatorname{Sym}^d(W))$
maps naturally to
$\operatorname{Sym}^{de}(W)$ but it's not an isomorphism.)

Finally $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ is the space of quadratic forms in a basis of $V$,
but I'm not sure if I would agree with the description as polynomials that can be written as sums of squares.
They aren't polynomials in whatever variables form the monomials spanning $V$,
and more importantly there's no positivity condition.
For example $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ includes elements like
$(xy)^2 - (xz)^2$, a linear combination of squares;
if you're okay with calling that a "sum", then it's true that every quadratic form is a sum, or linear combination, of squares
(but again these are not exactly quadratic forms).
If you want sums with positive coefficients,
then you are looking for a cone in the vector space of quadratic forms.

To try to be clear: if $V = \operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ is spanned by variables, then $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ can be identified with quadratic forms in the $x_i$ (as long as we're not in characteristic $2$),
and every element of $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ is a linear combination of squares, e.g., $x_i x_j = (1/4)((x_i+x_j)^2-(x_i-x_j)^2)$.
But if $V = \operatorname{Sym}^d(\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\})$
is already the space of degree $d$ polynomials in the $x_i$, then $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ is *not* the space of degree $2d$ polynomials in the $x_i$, it's just a space with a natural surjection onto that.

Comment: We can identify Sym^2 with quadratic forms in characteristic 2. I must have been thinking of the problem with sums of squares in characteristic 2, where not all quadratic forms are sums of squares. Sorry for any confusion.